# Running app using PM2 gives me a 502 error

Tags: node.js, nginx, pm2

I have a relatively basic Express app that I have sitting behind nginx.

Everything works fine when I run

`sudo node server.js`

I can access the website without incident.

However when I use

`sudo pm2 start server.js` I get an 'online' status and no errors (helpful), but when attempting to access the website I get a 502 error. The instructions for PM2 don't indicate any additional steps are required.

I've looked for solutions to this problem but they all seem slightly different (and there are a lot of them! I'm beginning to wonder if it works at all) - I've tried a few things, like targeting bin/www instead of server.js but no dice.

Do I need to perform additional setup for PM2 compatibility? Should I look for alternatives? What could be causing these problems?

Here is my current nginx config (improvements welcome), but I will stress that the setup works fine when not using PM2.

(Domain replaced with **X**)

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.X.co.uk;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/X.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/X.co.uk/privkey.pem;

  return 301 https://X.co.uk$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name X.co.uk;

  return 301 https://X.co.uk$request_uri;
}
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name X.co.uk;

  root /var/www/X;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/X.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/X.co.uk/privkey.pem;

  location / {
    proxy_pass https://localhost:4003;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/expires.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/cross-domain-fonts.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/h5bp/location/protect-system-files.conf;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing being logged? Can you access `localhost:4003` with a tool like cURL? Why are both NGINX _and_ your Node server doing TLS/SSL? Why are you running your Node app as root?

Comment: @robertklep I just went hunting for the PM2 logs and I did in fact track something down (sorry I'd checked nginx logs didnt think to look for PM2 ones) - EACCES error attempting to load the cert files (which is why I was running the app as sudo to begin with). So it seems running PM2 with sudo doesn't actually work as expected. Incidentally I copied over an nginx Elixir config that required that setup - if I can get away without referencing the cert files in my node app that would clearly simplify things, from what I read that was a requirement though. I'll do more reading.

Comment: Perhaps pm2 is dropping root privs, because it's generally not a good idea to run apps as root. I'm guessing that you did so to access the LetsEncrypt certs, but your Node app doesn't need to use TLS because NGINX is already handling that.

Comment: That's good news, thanks for the tip I'll investigate!

Comment: @robertklep got it working with a standard app.listen block - thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installed certbot. But

```
sudo pm2 delete server
sudo pm2 start server.js
```

did the trick and everything began to work as expected!